# como cubrir el 100% de altura de mi navbar desplegable

Tags: css, reactjs, scss

estoy desarrollando una aplicacion con `React` y quiero que sea responsiva, por lo que hice que cuando la pantalla sea maximo de 960px, haya un menú desplegable.

El problema que tengo es que cuando lo muestro, no cubre el 100% de altura, quedando una franja blanca encima, justo donde está el icono para abrir/cerrar el menú

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto dejo el codigo de cómo lo estoy haciendo..

**Navbar.js:**

```
class Navbar extends Component{
    state = { clicked: false}

    handleClick = () =>{
        this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <>
                <nav className='navbar-items'>
                    <img alt='mRadio' className='navbar-logo' src={require('../../assets/images/mRadio.png')}></img>
                    <div className='menu-icon' onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        <i className={this.state.clicked ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'}></i>
                    </div>
                    <ul className={this.state.clicked ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                        {MenuItems.map((item, index)=>{
                            return (
                                <li key={index}>
                                    <a className={item.cName} href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
                                </li>
                            )                            
                        })
                        }                   
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </>
        )  
    } 
}
```

`Navbar.scss`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px){
    .navbar-items{
        position: relative;
        
        .nav-menu{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 80px;
            left: -100%;
            opacity: 1;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
            
            .nav-links{
                display: none;
            }
        }

        .nav-menu.active{
            background: #444 ;
            left: 0;
            opacity: 0.9;        
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
            z-index: 1;
            position: absolute;
            .nav-links-mobile{
                
                text-align: center;
                padding: 8px;
                
                width: 100%;
                display: table;
                color: #fff;
                text-decoration: none;
                &:hover{
                    color: #bd1313;
                    background-color: #b6b6b6;
                }
            }
        }

        .navbar-logo{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            transform: translate(25%, 50%);
        }

        .menu-icon{
            
            display: block;
            position:absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
            font-size: 1.8rem;
            cursor: pointer;

            .fa-times{
                font-size: 2rem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y bueno el menu de los items no crea que sea necesario, perol es dejo un par por las dudas..

```
export const MenuItems = [
    {
        title: 'Soluciones',
        url: "#",
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: 'Quienes Somos',
        url: '#',
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: 'CARTELERÍA DIGITAL',
        url: '#',
        cName: 'nav-links-mobile'
    },
    {
        title: 'CONTACTO',
        url: '#',
        cName: 'nav-links-mobile'
    }
```

Cuando la pantalla supere los 960 pixeles, solo se van a mostrar unas opciones, y cuando sea como máximo 960, se van a mostrar otros, pero ésto no es relevante ya que ya pude hacer eso. El problema ahora es la barra de arriba.

Si utilizo height: 100%, el menú se va para arriba..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no se de react, pero probaste con `height: 100%;`?...

Comment: no funciona con `height: 100%`, se va para arriba el menu, dejo imagen para que puedan ver

Comment: Me parece que tu problema es que el estilo se lo estás aplicando a la lista que está dentro del nav, entonces solo la lista tiene ese estilo... deberías aplicarselo al contenedor, en este caso el nav. Si pudieras dejar un ejemplo reproducible aquí o en un jsfiddle sería más fácil probarlo.

Comment: Aquí te dejo un buen ejemplo de como hacer un buen navbar https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp Espero te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a ponerle `height: 100vh` en lugar de `height: 100%`?

Al ponerle el *height* al 100% lo que le estás diciendo es que ocupe todo el alto de su **contenedor**, y este alto dependerá de lo que tenga dentro. En cambio, si usas 100vh estás diciéndole que ocupe el 100% del alto del **viewport**, es decir, el alto total de la pantalla.